# OpenCart Call Different Controller

Tags: php, opencart

I have a custom module, and now want to call the `add()` function from `checkout/cart`. How do I call the controller and function?

I have tried `$this->load->controller('checkout/cart');` but this returns a fatal exception.

I am using OpenCart v 1.5.6.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenCart 1.5.*, `getChild` is used to load other controllers. Specifically, it is running a route to the desired controller and function. For example, `common/home` would load the `home` controller from the `common` group/folder. By adding a third option we specify a function. In this case, 'add' - `checkout/cart/add`.

```
class ControllerModuleModule1 extends Controller {
  protected function index() {
    ob_start();
    $this->getChild('checkout/cart/add');
    $this->response->output();
    $response = ob_get_clean();
  }
}
```

Most controllers don't return or echo anything, but specify what to output in the `$this->response` object. To get what is being rendered you need to call `$this->response->output();`. In the above code `$response` is the json string that `checkout/cart/add` echos.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the same issue, I use $this->load->controller("checkout/cart/add").

If I use getChild, this exception get thrown : "Call to undefined method Loader::getChild()".

What is the difference between the 2 methods? Is getChild better?

Comment: Yes, I am using v2. Is that what it's all about ?

Comment: I suspect so. I shall edit my question and answer to reflect the version of OC I am using. I recommend leaving your answer in place so future visitors can see both solutions and use the one that suits their needs most.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `getChild()` is it only works if the controller calls `$this->response->setOutput()` or `echo` at the end - producing actual output.  If on the other hand, you want to call a controller method that returns a variable response, it isn't going to work.  There is also no way to pass more than one argument since `getChild()` accepts only one argument to pass, `$args`.

My solution was to add this bit in 1.5.6.4 to **system/engine/loader.php** which allows you to load a controller and call it's methods in the same way as you would a model:

```
public function controller($controller) {
    $file  = DIR_APPLICATION . 'controller/' . $controller . '.php';
    $class = 'controller' . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $controller);

    if (file_exists($file)) { 
        include_once($file);

        $this->registry->set('controller_' . str_replace('/', '_', $controller), new $class($this->registry));
    } else {
        trigger_error('Error: Could not load controller ' . $controller . '!');
        exit();                 
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
$this->load->controller('catalog/example');
$result = $this->controller_catalog_example->myMethod($var1, $var2, $var3);
```