# Opencart - In controller, how to call a function from another controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, opencart

I have a controller (sale/order.php) with a function generateOrder(). In my another controller (settings.php), I need to call/execute generateOrder() function in sale/order.php controller. How is it possible? Thanks in advance.

I tried:
$ordercontroller = $this->load->controller('sale/order');
$this->ordercontroller->generateOrder();

Comment: Which version of opencart?

Comment: Check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017144/opencart-call-different-controller), if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to call a function from **sale/order.php** use

```
$this->load->controller("sale/order/generateOrder");
```